# Angular 4: How to get the text color at the current caret position in a content editable?

Tags: angular, contenteditable, text-editor, caret, textcolor

I have made my own small text editor, and I want to know how to get the color value at the current caret position. For example:

This is the value of my text editor:

```
This is a <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">test</span>
```

Which would look something like this in the editor:

[image]

I would like that my text editor changes color according to the posisiton of the caret, so either red or black in this case.

I am working in Angular 4 with a contenteditable div so a solution in this context would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, it is DOM manipulation. You need to find the element first. Here is some JS thought. You can put it into TS. var all = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var searchText = "test";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < all .length; i++) {
  if (all[i].textContent == searchText) {
    found = all[i];
    break;
  }
}

// At this level, you can access style attribute.
// found.style.color

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I wanna know the text color at the current caret/cursor. Not at the word 'test'. So if I would move my caret/cursor with the arrows i would get different colors according to the text color where its currently at.

Comment: hmm, then you can put something in onmouseover event. showColor(event) { console.log(event.target.style.color); }. Is this what you are referring to?